# How to transform row to collumn in csv file?

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, csv, csv-simple

```
2015-12-2119:30:00;ManagedElement=1,Equipment=1,Subrack=1

;pmEs
;0
```

I need this result

```
2015-12-2119:30:00;ManagedElement=1,Equipment=1,Subrack=1;pmEs;0
```

Extra data from comment:

```
2015-12-21 19:30:00;ManagedElement=1,Equipment=1,Subrack=1,Slot=27,PlugInUnit=1,ExchangeTer‌​minal=1,E1PhysPathTerm=PPS1 ;pmEs ;0
2015-12-21 09:30:00;ManagedElement=1,Equipment=1,Subrack=1,Slot=27,PlugInUnit=1,ExchangeTer‌​minal=1,E1PhysPathTerm=PPS1 ;pmSes ;0
2015-12-21 19:30:00;ManagedElement=1,Equipment=1,Subrack=1,Slot=27,PlugInUnit=1,ExchangeTer‌​minal=1,E1PhysPathTerm=PPS1 ;pmUas ;900
```

Comment: It is unclear what the input looks like. The examples at the start and end of the question are totally different from each other.

Answer (score 2):

Given your example which looks like it could be one of many records of some kind of log, each log record starting with `2015-`..., you can try this quick method:

```
tr -d '\n' < input.csv | sed 's/2015-/\n2015-/g' > output.csv
```

### Explanation

- Where `input.csv` contains lines looking like your example where what you want would always begin with `2015-`...
- `tr -d '\n'` deletes new lines. So we temporarily remove all new lines
- `< input.csv` feeds the contents of `input.csv` to standard input, in order for `tr` program to read it
- we then use `sed` to search for `2015-` and replace with a new line preceding `2015-` to get the lines back that we do want. Otherwise your input seems to be from a log and usually there are multiple entries/records in a log, just `tr -d '\n'` would make one huge continuous line with all different time-stamped entries merged together, and would not allow you to discern individual time-stamped entries. Thus we use this `sed` to ensure the final output has one record per line, via searching for a recognizable record separator such as `2015-` and prefix it with a new line
- `> output.csv` saves results to `output.csv`
- this will not work of course if records don't start with `2015-` for example we are near year's end, soon it will be `2016-` so you would need to revise next year to 2016.

### More Advanced Version

Or:

```
tr -d '\n' < input.csv | sed 's/\([[:digit:]]\{4\}\)-/\n\1-/g' > output.csv
```

- works the same but for `sed` uses basic regular expressions to look for "year-" by looking for four digits, followed by a dash
- so you don't have to worry about year changes
- but just slightly more typing and harder to remember, if you aren't familiar with regular expressions yet nor have this info on you when you are required to use it